# Atribuir um float no main() para um struct dentro de outro struct

Tags: c, struct

Estou fazer um exercicio e não consigo entender oque estou errando nessa parte final.
Preciso basicamente fazer um struct para cadastrar um funcionário, e dentro desse struct utilizar um outro struct com o valor dos salários (bruto e líquido) de 3 meses, somar o total e fazer a media. No fim preciso imprimir o valor do salário líquido de cada mês (além do total bruto, total liquido e a media).

O problema é que não estou entendo como faço para no main() colocar um valor float em cada uma das 3 posições desse struct. Estou tentando fazer isso:

```
typedef struct salario{
        float sal, bonus, salBruto, salLiq;
        float tSal, tBonus, tBruto, tLiq;    
    } Salario;
    
typedef struct cadastro{
      char nome[15];
      char rua [15];
      int numero;
      char bairro[15];
      struct salario sala[2];
      float MediaTrimestre;
    } Cadastro;
```

E dai mais em baixo no código:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
if (salario.salBruto >1000){
        salario.tLiq = salario.tLiq + (salario.salBruto * 0.8);
        // salario.salLiq = salario.salBruto *0.8; // tentei utilizar isso pra depois usar salario.salLiq mas ainda não resolveu.
        cadastro.sala[i] = salario.salBruto*0.8; // <=== PROBLEMA AQUI!!!!!!! 
      }
      else{
        salario.tLiq = salario.tLiq + (salario.salBruto * 0.95);
      }
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct salario{
    float sal, bonus, salBruto, salLiq;
    float tSal, tBonus, tBruto, tLiq;    
} Salario;

typedef struct cadastro{
  char nome[15];
  char rua [15];
  int numero;
  char bairro[15];
  struct salario sala[2];
  float MediaTrimestre;
} Cadastro;

int main() {
  Cadastro cadastro;
  Salario salario;
  salario.tSal = 0, salario.tBonus = 0, salario.tBruto = 0, salario.tLiq=0;
  int i;      

  // CADASTRO: NOME, RUA, NUMERO, BAIRRO
  printf("Nome: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]", cadastro.nome);
       

  printf("Rua: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]", cadastro.rua);
        

  printf("Número: ");
  scanf(" %d", &cadastro.numero);

  printf("Bairro: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]", cadastro.bairro);
      
  //

  // CADASTRO SALÁRIO 3 MESES
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("\nSalário %dº Mês: ", i+1);
    scanf(" %f", &salario.sal);
    salario.tSal = salario.tSal + salario.sal;
   
        //printf("\n%f\n", salario.tSal); // print para checar o sal se ta add correto
    printf("Bônus %dº Mês: ", i+1);
    scanf(" %f", &salario.bonus);
    salario.tBonus = salario.tBonus + salario.bonus;
        //printf("\n%f\n", salario.bonus); // print para checar o bonus se ta add correto
    
    salario.salBruto = salario.sal + salario.bonus; // bruto de cada mês para calcular o liquido mensal
    salario.tBruto = salario.tSal + salario.tBonus; //total que recebeu nos 3 meses
    
      if (salario.salBruto >1000){
        salario.tLiq = salario.tLiq + (salario.salBruto * 0.8);
        cadastro.sala[i] = 0; // <=== PROBLEMA AQUI!!!!!!!
      }
      else{
        salario.tLiq = salario.tLiq + (salario.salBruto * 0.95);
      }
    }
  //
  /* resto do código */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observando bem o problema, parece que você está tentando definir uma float para cada elemento do array cadastro.sala, sendo que cada elemento é uma struct (não uma float).
A chamada de cada `cadastro.sala[i]` é uma struct, não um float, então não dá pra jogar um número direto ali.

Acho que você quer definir um campo de cada uma das structs, não ela toda. Digamos que esse campo seja o salBruto (estou supondo baseado na lógica do seu código, mas poderia ser tBruto também). Então, o trecho problemático seria substituído por:

`cadastro.sala[i].salBruto = salario.tLiq + (salario.salBruto * 0.95);`

E no segundo trecho:

`cadastro.sala[i].salBruto = 0;`

Troque o campo `salBruto` por outro que achar necessário na sua lógica e estiver definido na struct salario. Mas em resumo, só um campo float deve receber um valor float.